# Prob. 14, Sec. 3.8 in Erwine Kreyszig's INTRODUCTORY FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS WITH APPLICATIONS: A Hermitian positive semi-definite form

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a complex vector space, and let the map $h \colon X \times X \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfy the following conditions:

For all $x, y, z \in X$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$,

(i) $h(x+y, z) = h(x,z) + h(y,z)$,

(ii) $h(\alpha x, y) = \alpha h(x,y)$,

(iii) $h(x,y) = \overline{h(y,x)}$, and

(iv) $h(x,x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h(x,x) \geq 0$.

Then how to show that 
$$\vert h(x,y) \vert^2 \leq h(x,x) h(y,y) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in X?$$

My effort:

We note that, for all $x, y \in X$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, 
$$h(x, \alpha y) = \overline{h(\alpha y, x)} = \overline{ \alpha h(y,x) } = \overline{\alpha} \overline{h(y,x)} = \overline{\alpha} h(x,y);$$
that is, 
$$h(x, \alpha y) = \overline{\alpha} h(x,y).$$

Now 
$$ 
\begin{align*}
0 & \leq h(x - \alpha y, x - \alpha y) \\ 
& = h(x, x- \alpha y ) - \alpha h(y, x- \alpha y) \\
& = h(x,x) - \overline{\alpha} h(x,y) - \alpha h(y,x) + \vert \alpha \vert^2 h(y,y) \\
& = h(x, x) + \vert \alpha \vert^2 h(y,y) - 2 \Re \left( \overline{ \alpha } h(x,y) \right). 
\end{align*}
$$

What next? Which value should we give $\alpha$ in order to arrive at our desired inequality?

Answer (score 0):

First, choose $\alpha:= h(x,y)\beta$ for some real number $\beta$ in order to get rid of the real part. Assuming $h(x,y)\neq 0$ (otherwise there is nothing to prove), we have 
$$0\leqslant h(x,x)+\beta^2|h(x,y)|^2 |h(y,y)|-2\beta |h(x,y)|^2,$$
hence 
$$\frac{h(x,x)}{|h(x,y)|^2 }+\beta^2h(y,y)\geqslant 2\beta.$$ 
Assume that $h(y,y)\neq 0$. Completing the squares, we find the choice $\beta=h(y,y)^{-1/2}$, which yields 
$$\frac{h(x,x)}{|h(x,y)|^2}-\frac 1{h(y,y)}\geqslant 0.$$ 
If $h(y,y)=0$, then from the non-negativeness of $h(x, x) + \vert \alpha \vert^2 h(y,y) - 2 \Re \left( \overline{ \alpha } h(x,y) \right)$ for each $\alpha$, we infer that 
$$h(x,x)\geqslant 2\beta|h(x,y)|^2,$$
hence we should have $h(x,y)=0$.

Comment: how do you arrive at the first inequality? And, how can we choose $\beta$ as you have if $h(y,y) = 0$?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud I have edited.